# Trouble with equals method

Tags: java, collections

I have created a class called student which has an equals method as shown below.
My problem is this.

I create an instance of student class and add it to ArrayList, Now I want to check weather the list contains a duplicate of student object. When i try this with the below equals function its giving wrong result.

for eg.

```
    Student stud1= new Student(101,"Student1");
    Student stud5= new Student(105,"Student5");
    Student stud6= new Student(105,"Student5");
    list1.add(stud1);
    list1.add(stud5);
    System.out.println(list1.contains( new Student(105,"Student5")));// outputting false



class Student{
int sid;
String sname;

public Student(int sid,String sname){
    this.sid=sid;
    this.sname=sname;
}

public String toString(){
    return ""+this.sid;
}



public boolean equals(Student test){
    return  this.sid==test.sid; 
}
```

}

but when I replace the equals function with the one below its giving a correct result.. Why is that? Technically there is no difference right? Could you please help me as how is the JVM looking at the code..

```
    public boolean equals(Object cond){
    if(cond instanceof Student){
        Student test = (Student) cond;
        return test.sid==this.sid;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first `equals(Student)` method doesn't override the `Object#equals(Object)` method. Hence with that, the `list.contains(Student)` method will invoke the default `Object#equals()` method, and which compares the references using `==`. So, for two different objects, it will return `false`.

Comment: We say that every object is an instance of a class. So in that sense dosen't Student become an Object?

Comment: @user2900314 well that is true, but this is not how overriding works. While overriding, you can't change the signature of the method. You can give covariant types in parameters. Covariant type would work with return types though.

Comment: Once you have implemented the equals method why not store them in a set?

Comment: Just a minor addition: If you used the @Override annotation, your compiler would have thrown a Compiler error, since your equals method does not really override anything.

Answer (score 1):

The contains javadoc states

> Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).

You must override `equals(Object)`, in your example you define `equals(Student)`, which is not used when calling `list1.contains(`.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not the same.
In order for the equals to work properly, you need to override the method from superclass (Object). And the overridden method signature is

```
public boolean equals(Object cond){}
```

By doing this `public boolean equals(Student test){}` you are effectively overloading the method. Thus it is no longer the call back method and the equals method of Object is getting called.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public boolean equals(Object cond)
```

and

```
 public boolean equals(Student cond)
```

has two different method signatures

The first one, You are overriding the Object class's equals method. (Same signature as Object.equals

The second one you overload the method. with different signature.

to override, the method signature must be similar.

That is why equals(Object other) works.